# Bypass Django admin login by using another authentication method

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication

Is there a way, when hitting Django admin site, it redirects to a 3rd party authentication page. User logs in there, then gets redirected back to Admin site without having to log in again?

Basically I want to replace Django admin login by another authentication, so I can insert a link to my web app and admins can access admin page right away.

EDIT:

did a bit more research and will refine my problem.

Say I want to login from `http://localhost:8000/admin/login/`, I assume I need to redirect the user/admin to the 3rd party login page, then once the auth is successful, I should redirect him back to the next page after login. Where/what should I modify?

EDIT2:

I'm following this example

https://auth0.com/docs/sso/current/single-page-apps

Could get the server to run on `5000` but the auth still fails and returns 400

How do I get from my React app in `localhost:3000` to my django admin page in `localhost:8000` without needing to log in again?

Comment: Do you want to do this to change the design of the login page or do you actually want to use a different authentication backend?

Comment: Sounds like you want something like OAuth. [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can handle this.

Comment: @markwalker_ I'm trying to use a different auth backend

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible, you can use authenticate functions to authenticate your request, so when your come back from your 3rd party authentication page you get your response being success or failed and run authenticate function and now your user will be logged... this is kinda a dirty way to do that...

You can also write your own Authentication method and setup at your settings

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: I'm sorry I'm super raw on django's authentication. I've been just using the default django one without really thinking much. How is it done exactly? Suppose my admin page script is all in `admin.py`, do I start there? Is `@login_required` needed here?

Comment: @JChao What's wrong with django's authentication system that makes you want to change it? Given that it's such an important part of security I wouldn't recommend it be something you do until you're really experienced with django.

Comment: @markwalker_ I agree with you. However we're experimenting non-native authentication. Auth0 is the one I'm playing with right now. It seems like the direction our company wants to go, so I don't get a say on this part. I guess it's good for me to learn as well.

Comment: the decorators like @Login_required you use in your regular views, if you use that they will bring the admin default login page to you login before continue to this page... since you want to use it outside django, in your regular login view you send it to external link (inside your django project or no) get the response that you expect in post, or get, or any other way and check if that you expected, than run the function authenticate() passing the login and the user password

Comment: so that way you authenticate it in your views, without needing the interating of your end-user with your django login main page

Comment: @DiegoVinícius so i should create a separate views.py to incorporate this? Do I rewrite the `is_authenticated` method? Seems like we are using jwt, so I can return`True` if `jwt` contains admin role?

Comment: depends if you want to hit your authentication in custom page or in django admin login page... if is in custom page just process your jwt return, if true use authenticate() function not is_authenticated, because is_auth... is just for check if is authenticated in your backends... since you still using django and your jwt is one step more you will force your django to authenticate after you get True response form your jwt